# Spring Data Redis NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-redis

When I try to inject repository that implements CrudRepository from Spring Data Redis, I get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [bluh.bluh.repository.XxxRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

However configuration is there, it's annotated with  **@EnableRedisRepositories("bluh.bluh.repository")**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        return template;
    }

}
```

Repository interface looks like:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface XxxRepository extends CrudRepository<String, String> { }
```

I've been through http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/ , there's nothing new for me. I wonder what did I miss and I'll appreciate any inputs.

I use Spring Data Redis 1.7.2.RELEASE, Spring Boot 1.3.6.RELEASE

Comment: No qualifying bean of type... of what type? can you post the full exception message?

Comment: Spring Data Redis Repositories are applicable only for complex types. Your Repository declares `String` as the domain class. Using a `String` identifier is ok. The usual declarations look like `interface XxxRepository extends CrudRepository<Xxx, String> { }` or `interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> { }`. That's why you don't get the bean created.

Comment: Nope. The same thing happens with complex types too. Sure enough I have tried Xxx. My Xxx looks like                                                                        @RedisHash("xxx")
public class Xxx {

    @Id
    private String xxxId; }

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible test case? Gist or Github repo?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe56c976e8772e114f36e0a5d0b51a7a

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in my project.  Anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Same issue here. The solution posted below did not seem to do the trick for me...

Comment: I think I figured out my issue... see my response to the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. In my case the versions were not the problem but the annotation needed an explicit `basePackages` like below:

`@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages = "my.base.pkg")`

- Using springboot - 1.5.11 and spring-data-redis-1.8.11

Comment: Needed this with springboot - 2.4.1 and spring-data-redis - 2.7.7

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue, and realized it was a version problem.

I was using spring-boot v1.3.8, and was pulling in spring-data-redis v1.7.5 as a dependency. I was getting the error posted in the question above when trying to autowire a spring-data-redis repository with these versions.

I tried upgrading to spring-boot v.1.4.2. This version of spring-boot comes with a starter called "spring-boot-starter-data-redis" that pulls down spring-data-redis v1.7.5 and jedis v2.8.2. I followed the same configuration as provided in the docs, and I finally got it to work!

I'm guessing there are some compatibility issues with spring-boot v1.3.8 and spring-data-redis v1.7.x. This was somewhat confirmed, by the fact that spring-boot 1.3.8 came with a starter called spring-boot-starter-redis that pulled down v1.6.5 of spring-data-redis. Since the @EnableRedisRepositories annotation was only included in 1.7.+, it looks like an upgrade is required to get the repositories functionality to work properly.

tl;dr try upgrading spring boot to version.latest, and pull in spring-data-redis from spring-boot-starter-data-redis.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late but for anyone else having this issue:

I just sat pulling my hair out with this. Downloaded the GIT examples and noticed the entity was annotated with @RedisHash("hash_name_here"):

```
@RedisHash("MyDataThingies")
public class MyDataThingy{
    @Id
    public String id
}
```

Now it has connection issues but I know why :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue in my own project... Was the @RedisHash annotation the only thing missing? 

I'm also using hibernate to instantiate other repositories... I'm thinking that maybe having 2 repository loaders might be confusing to the framework? The issue I'm running in to is it seems that my controller is being instantiated before my spring related beans and their dependencies.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured out my problem... It appears to be a version issue. I was on spring boot 1.3.8 and was pulling in spring-data-redis as a dependency (the repository feature is a version 1.7.x feature of spring-data-redis, and spring-boot 1.3.8 only comes with v 1.6.5 of spring-data-redis). 

Spring boot 1.4.0 has a spring-data-redis starter that pulls in 1.7.5 of spring-data-redis automatically, and when I configured the example above with those versions, my application worked. 

So make sure you're using spring boot 1.4.+ if you want to use redis repositories!